# data appendBytes:&buffer length:len similar functionality in C#

Tags: c#, objective-c

I am working on a project where two softwares communicates with each other. One of the application  is developed using Objective C and the other using C#. Both softwares uses encoding and decoding scheme which is specific to this software. The software developed using objective c used `[data appendBytes:&buffer length:len]` to append bytes to a buffer of specific length.

I am developing the other half of the software in C#. I am looking for similar functionality `[data appendBytes:&buffer length:len]` in C#.

Please can any one suggest how this can be done?

Answer (score 0):

The closest I can think of I/O wise is a memory stream:

```
byte [] buffer = new byte[10];
//fill buffer
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
ms.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length); //appends bytes to the end of the stream
```

Depending on where you want your data written (file, memory, network) there are many other [Stream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.aspx) derived classes - that would be a good starting point.